# how to run a wordpress plugin page from cpanel cron job

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, cpanel

In my wordpress website I created a plugin that fetches json data from another remote website and save this data in db.

I created a file inside my plugin (my_plugin_folder/update.php) that makes the request to the other website api and do the job.

now on the **cpanel**, I need to add a cron job to run this file daily, what the cron job command should be? I need something like this command

```
lynx -dump https://example.com/path_to_my_file
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps for creating a cronjob in cPanel:

1. Login to the cPanel account
2. Click on the "Cron Jobs" icon which is under the Advanced section (Ask your hosting provider to enable this feature if it is missing)
3. Under the "Common Settings" header you can select a commonly used rate at which your cronjob will run such as "Once per 5 minutes". This will automatically configure the cronjob time setting for you. If you would like to manually select the time period you are welcome to do so. The cron time specification is explained in depth in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab), or you can use an online tool like https://crontab.guru to help.
4. Under the "Command" header, enter the command that you would like to be run.

In your case you could either enter a command that makes a request via HTTP like one of these:

`lynx --dump https://example.com/path_to_my_file`

`curl -Ls https://example.com/path_to_my_file`

Or you could run the script directly like this:

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/cpanelusername/public_html/path/to/php/file.php`

How you actually run the command depends entirely on how the script was written.

I've written an article that outlines the process here:

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360053606793-How-to-create-a-cron-job-in-the-cPanel-user-interface

I also wrote another article that explains how you can avoid and troubleshoot some of the most common problems when creating cronjobs in case you have trouble getting it to work:

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360053675953-How-to-troubleshoot-user-level-cron-issues

Comment: sorry but this is not what I actually need, I am not asking how to add a cronjob in cpanel, my question is what the command itself should be, i.e what `path_to_my_file` should be as I am on wordpress

Comment: @anwar Either login via SSH or use the Terminal icon in cPanel. Run the following command to find the full path to your plugin file:
`find $(pwd) -iname update.php`
Then add the cron command like this:
`/usr/local/bin/php /path/to/your/plugin/file/update.php`
It is very important that you use full paths to both the PHP binary and the plugin file if you want to avoid headeaches.